# Is there a way to loop through different columns from left to right, and count up if the first number it meets per row is a 1?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

Say we have a dataframe

```
data = {'Column a':     [ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5], 
        'Column b':     [ 3 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 4], 
        'Column 1':     [ 3 , 2 , 1 , 1 , 3],
        'Column 2':     [ 4 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 2],
        'Column 3':     [ 1 , '', '', 2 , 4],
        'Column 4':     [ '', '', '', '', 1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

Column a is an ID, column b is the number of columns for the ID. Column 1-4 takes some values for each ID.

I need to create a loop that looks through each column from column 4 to column 1. If the first number it encounters is a '1', I need it to count up by one.

```
coa cob co1 co2 co3 co4
 1   3   3   4   1
 2   2   2   2
 3   2   1   1
 4   3   1   2   2
 5   4   3   2   4   1
```

- So for the first row, it will count 1, because the last column for
  that row has a 1.
- For the second row, it will not count up, because
  there is no 1.
- For the third row, it will only count one 1, because    it is only
  the first 1 (from the left) that counts.
- For the fourth row, it will not count anything, because the 1 is
  not in the last row.
- For the last row, it will count 1, because there is a 1 in the
  last row.

So in total I want this to return 3.

My issue is with the looping function and how the columns change per row, I only know how to do this if all the values were in column 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `replace` and `ffill` like:

```
df['eq1'] = df.iloc[:,-4:].replace('', np.nan)\
              .ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]\
              .eq(1).cumsum()
print (df)
   Column a  Column b  Column 1  Column 2 Column 3 Column 4  eq1
0         1         3         3         4        1             1
1         2         2         2         2                      1
2         3         2         1         1                      2
3         4         3         1         2        2             2
4         5         4         3         2        4        1    3
```

Comment: Ahhh `.ffill` is so elegant. I constantly forget this because there's no way to do like `df.last(axis=1)` but really i just need to remember `df.ffill(1).iloc[:, -1]`

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm trying to learn and understand why this works. I tried splitting it up, but it is not much helpful. Would you do me the favor of explaining the steps here? @Ben. T

Comment: @nielsen the first `iloc` select the last 4 columns with `-4:`, in these columns, `replace` change empty string with nan, that can be `ffill` along axis=1 (aka along the columns) with the last value existing. So for example the third row, column 3 and 4 will be filled with 1 as it is the last value available in this row at column 2. the second `iloc` select then only the last column with `-1`, just filled with the last value available. Finally, you check where the value is equal (`eq`) to 1, giving True or False, and `cumsum` is cumulative sum so everytime it meets a True, the value increase

Comment: Ah that's so clever. So ffill basically just repeats the last seen value for a row along an axis and it knows which column to start in.

Answer (score 2):

Provide a list of the columns in reverse order and use `idxmax` to find the first non missing value in each row from 4-1. We will use `where` to remove rows that have fully missing values as those mess up `.idxmax`.

Use `lookup` to grab the values for each row and then see how many equal 1.

```
cols = [f'Column {i}' for i in range(1,5)]

s = df.loc[:, cols[::-1]].ne('')
s = s.idxmax(1).where(s.notnull().all(1)).dropna()

(df.lookup(s.index, s) == 1).sum()
#3
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `where`, `ffill` and `sum`. Use `iloc` with `-1` to dynamically pick last column without knowing its name

```
out = df.where(df.ne('')).ffill(1).iloc[:,-1].eq(1).sum()

In [30]: out
Out[30]: 3
```

To specifically apply to 4 columns, just add an additional slicing before `where` and slicing on `column 4` instead of `iloc`

```
cols = ['Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3', 'Column 4'] 

In [39]: df[cols].where(df.ne('')).ffill(1)['Column 4'].eq(1).sum()
Out[39]: 3
```

Comment: Is there a way to explicitly define that this these functions applies to columns 1-4. columns = ['Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3', 'Column 4'] . In case you have more columns. @Andy L.